# Retrieve password connection string Microsoft access ODBC

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, odbc, connection-string

I have an old Microsoft Access program for old client in my company and they forget the connection string. I have linked tables to SQL server database using ODBC - can I retrieve username and password? I already tried to get the connection string using the property In the Design view but the username and password are hidden. Please help me. Thanks.

[image]

Comment: If there are **Pass-Through queries**, it's visible in their properties.

Answer (score 1):

It's only hidden in the UI for linked tables. The actual connect string is readily available in VBA, e.g. in the Immediate window:

```
Debug.Print CurrentDb.TableDefs("MyLinkedTable").Connect
```

Comment: thank's for your response. it return connection string without password or user name the resault is : ODBC;Description=adsdsad;DRIVER=SQL Server;SERVER=DESKTOP-4MQUG1T\SQLEXPRESS;APP=Microsoft Office 2016;DATABASE=contoso

Comment: "Debug.Print CurrentDb.TableDefs("dbo_AspNetUserClaims").Connect" that's what  I put in Immediate window

Comment: That may be correct. You can choose to not save the password when linking, and then you have to provide it when opening the table. In your case, the application probably holds the password, so study the code to look this up.

Comment: after searching pretty sure there is no password in the code. Is there any chance that ms access saving the password as encrypted file?

Comment: Maybe it's using Windows authentication. @Ibrahimwahbi